# How to make a barrier in p5js but then you can enter only through a specific door

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am creating a game in p5js, in which burgers are going around randomly, and there is a big guy whose mouth opens whenever burgers get close. The burgers should only enter through the mouth of the big guy, and should not go through the big guy. The big guy can move up and down. So I was wondering how to make a barrier in which the burgers can only enter through the moving mouth.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an ancient game *[Pong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong)*. I wonder what would happen if a burger crash into the BIG GUY's face?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Comment: Rabbid76's comment is right you should create an example otherwise your question is too vague: There are dozen of ways to achieve what you want to do. For example you could compute the collisions by yourself or you could use [p5play](https://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/) to handle your sprite and their collisions or [matterjs](https://brm.io/matter-js/) or one of the multiple existing libraries.